# How to delete multiple objects with the same key in aws s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, prisma

### TLDR; How can I delete image replicas in subfolders of s3 with the same key as the original image?

I've got a prisma server and upload images from my app to my s3 bucket through the prisma backend. Moreover, I run a lambda function to resize these images on-the-fly if requested.

**Here's the process of the lambda function**

- A user requests a resized asset from an S3 bucket through its static
  website hosting endpoint. The bucket has a routing rule configured to
  redirect to the resize API any request for an object that cannot be
  found.
- Because the resized asset does not exist in the bucket, the
  request is temporarily redirected to the resize API method.
- The user’s browser follows the redirect and requests the resize operation via API Gateway.
- The API Gateway method is configured to trigger a
  Lambda function to serve the request.
- The Lambda function downloads
  the original image from the S3 bucket, resizes it, and uploads the
  resized image back into the bucket as the originally requested key.
- When the Lambda function completes, API Gateway permanently redirects
  the user to the file stored in S3.
- The user’s browser requests the
  now-available resized image from the S3 bucket.
- Subsequent requests
  from this and other users will be served directly from S3 and bypass
  the resize operation.
- If the resized image is deleted in the future,
  the above process repeats and the resized image is re-created and
  replaced into the S3 bucket.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/

---

This brings me to the following issue:
Whenever I delete an image-node with a key in Prisma I can delete the object with the same key from aws s3, yet I won't touch the resized replicas of it in the subfolders of the respective resolutions. How can I achieve this? I tried using aws' deleteObjects() by passing in only one key as shown below. However, this only deletes the original image at the root of the bucket.

**Here's the lambda functions implementation**

```
exports.processDelete = async ( { id, key }, ctx, info) => {

  const params = {
    Bucket: 'XY',
    Delete: {
      Objects: [
        {
          Key: key, 
        },
      ],
      Quiet: false
    }
  }

  // Delete from S3
  const response = await s3
    .deleteObjects(
      params,
      function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
      }
    ).promise()

  // Delete from Prisma
  await ctx.db.mutation.deleteFile({ where: { id } }, info)

  console.log('Successfully deleted file!')
}
```

Comment: The object key is `full/path/prefix/filename.ext`.  Deleting `filename.ext` deletes the file of that name from the root of the bucket.  If you want to delete other files, you need to pass their entire object key, because by itself, `filename.ext` refers *only* to the object with exactly that key -- not any other similarly-named objects, because their object key is not actually "the same." Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I understand. I'm wondering how can implement somewhat of a cascading deletion of all resized images relating to the original file that is being deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I'm only allowing the resizing of certain resolutions, I ended up doing the following:

```
exports.processDelete = async ( { id, key }, ctx, info) => {
  const keys = [
    '200x200/' + key,
    '293x293/' + key,
    '300x300/' + key,
    '400x400/' + key,
    '500x500/' + key,
    '600x600/' + key,
    '700x700/' + key,
    '800x800/' + key,
    '900x900/' + key,
    '1000x1000' + key,
  ]

  const params = {
    Bucket: 'XY',
    Delete: {
      Objects: [
        {
          Key: key, 
        },
        {
          Key: keys[0], 
        },
        {
          Key: keys[1], 
        },
        {
          Key: keys[2], 
        },
        {
          Key: keys[3], 
        },
        {
          Key: keys[4], 
        },
        {
          Key: keys[5], 
        },
        {
          Key: keys[6], 
        },
        {
          Key: keys[7], 
        },
        {
          Key: keys[8], 
        },
        {
          Key: keys[9], 
        },
      ],
      Quiet: false
    }
  }
```

If there is a more elegant way, please let me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar time ago. We storaged the images like `path/to/my/image/11222333.jpg` and the renditions in `path/to/my/image/11222333/200x200.jpg` So when delete 112233.jpg we just need to list all renditions inside of the folder and delete them.